# Как увеличить на 1 значение ячейки в конкретном столбце таблицы в SQL?

Tags: sql

У меня имеется обработчик инлайн кнопки в чат боте. По нажатию кнопки проверяется существует ли такая запись, если нет тогда добавляется запись, если да -  значение колонки much должно увеличиваться на 1. Решил реализовать через IF. Все работает, ошибок не выдает, но добавляет все равно отдельно запись, а не плюсует... В чем может быть проблема?

---

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='doner1') async def
donecallback(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer(text="Добавлено в корзину", show_alert=True)
    username = call.message.chat.username
    user_id = call.message.chat.id
    db = sqlite3.connect('FVShop.db')
    cur = db.cursor()
    sht = cur.execute("SELECT*FROM basket WHERE (user_id OR 'Blue Razz Ice') AND much>=1")
    if sht is not True:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO basket (username,user_id, product) VALUES(?,?,?)", [username,user_id,'Blue Razz Ice']) 
    elif sht is True: 
        cur.execute("UPDATE basket SET much = much + 1 WHERE
[(user_id=user_id OR username=username) AND 'Blue Razz Ice']")
    db.commit() 
    db.close()
```

Comment: Скорее всего ваше условие `if sht is not True:` не выполняется. Проверьте, что возвращает ваш селект и какое значение sht перед if. Может вы не дожидаетесь ответа?

Comment: вот как раз таки False почему то не выполняется, а is not True - создает запись

Comment: Да, опечатался, однако сути не меняет. Посмотрите, чему у вас равен sht перед вашим if

Comment: не совсем понимаю, что нужно сделать

Comment: Перед if добавьте строчку `print(sht)`

Comment: вот что выдало <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x00000251CC6885E0>

Comment: тогда попробуйте print(bool(sht))

Comment: Если нет не одной записи выдает False, если уже есть одна запись выдает True

Comment: Я кое-что подправил. Сейчас if sht is None, а elif is not None. И теперь появилась ошибка связанная с отсутствием колонки в сроке UPDATE - sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: (`user_id`=user_id OR `username`=username) AND 'Blue Razz Ice'